# How can I calculate the hyperfine structure of a $p$-orbital?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen, orbitals, hyperfine-structure

I have a little problem with the calculation of the hyperfine structure of the 3p orbital in the hydrogen atom.
The Hamiltonian is:

[image]

Were  [image] represents the magnetic moment of the proton and [image] the magnetic moment of the electron.

I calculated the spected value for the first term and for the last term, but I don't know how to calculate the second term. A lot of textbooks calculate this only for a s orbital where l=0 but I'm looking this for a p orbital where l=1.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the $\hat{r}$? Try expressing it in terms of $\theta$, $\phi$, and Cartesian unit vectors.

Comment: The problem is that for l=1 you have 3 differents spherical harmonics (m=-1,0,1) and I don't know wich I have to choice because for the spected value you have to consider the wave function wich depends on the value of m

Comment: In English I think you mean *expected* value. Wouldn’t you have to calculate three expected values for the three $m$ states? Maybe they will then turn out to be equal.

Comment: I was thinking and I concluded that I have to make a matrix 3x3 because it is not diagonal in this base.

Comment: If you come up with your own solution, please provide a formal answer.  This is allowed on Physics SE and it means the system does not have another unanswered question on it's list.

Comment: @StephenG If I can solve it, I will put the answer here! Now I'm just listening different ideas and thinking about the problem.